# Getting a JsonSerializationException when deserializing an object with $id

Tags: c#, .net, json.net, azure-cosmosdb

I have a situation in which PreserveReferencesHandling.All is set on the JSON Serializer settings, which makes data to be created with automatically generated $id, and seems to be that is causing deserialization errors of the data.

I have a code snippet in which I have been able to reproduce an error. You can run it on your local machine an try out:

```
class Program
{
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        CosmosClient client = new CosmosClient("https://xxxx.documents.azure.com:443/", 
            new DefaultAzureCredential(), GetCosmosClientOptions());

        string databaseId = "Test";
        var database = client.GetDatabase(databaseId);
        string collectionId = "Test";
        var container = database.GetContainer(collectionId);
        var requestOptions = new QueryRequestOptions();

        var entity = new Entity
        {
            id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
            Name = "test",
            Comments = new List<Detail>(),
            Item = new Item
            {
                itemid = "7"
            }
        };
        await container.CreateItemAsync(entity);

        //var baseQuery = container.GetItemLinqQueryable<Entity>(requestOptions: requestOptions);

        //using (var setIterator = baseQuery.ToFeedIterator())
        //{
        //    while (setIterator.HasMoreResults)
        //    {
        //        foreach (var item in await setIterator.ReadNextAsync())
        //        {
        //        }
        //    }
        //}
    }

    protected static CosmosClientOptions GetCosmosClientOptions()
    {
        var cosmosClientOptions = new CosmosClientOptions()
        {
            ConnectionMode = ConnectionMode.Direct,
            Serializer = new CosmosJsonNetSerializer(new JsonSerializerSettings()
            {
                MetadataPropertyHandling = MetadataPropertyHandling.Ignore,
                ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore,
                PreserveReferencesHandling = PreserveReferencesHandling.All,
                NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Include,
                TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.None,
            })
        };

        return cosmosClientOptions;
    }

}

public class Entity
{
    public string id;
    public string Name;
    public Item Item;
    public List<Detail> Comments;
}

public class Item
{
    public string itemid;
}

public class Comment
{
    public string id;
}

public class Detail
{
    public string detailId;
}
```

The CosmosJsonNetSerializer in the above code snippet is a custom serializer. The source is here: https://pastebin.com/jSNfzUpa

If you run the code, the create statement in the above code will throw an error:

```
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: 'Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[CosmosErrorDebugging.Detail]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.
To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection type like an array or List<T>) that can be deserialized from a JSON object. JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON object.
Path 'Comments.$id', line 1, position 119.'
```

However the document will be created successfully. Here is the document it created, note the $id that was automatically generated:

```
{
  "id": "da82f504-ebbd-4e4c-8e02-a5e454f52435",
  "$id": "1",
  "Name": "test",
  "Item": {
    "itemid": "7"
  },
  "Comments": []
}
```

Then, comment out the create line and uncomment the code block in the snippet above to do a read:

```
        //await container.CreateItemAsync(entity);

        var baseQuery = container.GetItemLinqQueryable<Entity>(requestOptions: requestOptions);

        using (var setIterator = baseQuery.ToFeedIterator())
        {
            while (setIterator.HasMoreResults)
            {
                foreach (var item in await setIterator.ReadNextAsync())
                {
                }
            }
        }
```

You will get the same error again at setIterator.ReadNextAsync()

```
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: 'Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[CosmosErrorDebugging.Detail]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.
To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection type like an array or List<T>) that can be deserialized from a JSON object. JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON object.
Path '[6].Comments.$id', line 1, position 1876.'
```

The thing is I already have a lot of data with $id. And I need the read to work without throwing any error. I have tried to set PreserveReferencesHandling.None but I still get the same error on already created data with $id.

**EDIT**: here are the exception details:

```
Exception: {"Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {\"name\":\"value\"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[CosmosErrorDebugging.Detail]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.
To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection type like an array or List<T>) that can be deserialized from a JSON object. JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON object.
Path '[6].Comments.$id', line 1, position 1876."}

Data: {System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal}

HResult: -2146233088

Helplink: null

Inner Exception: null

Message: "Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {\"name\":\"value\"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[CosmosErrorDebugging.Detail]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.
To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection type like an array or List<T>) that can be deserialized from a JSON object. JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON object.
Path '[6].Comments.$id', line 1, position 1876."

Source: "Newtonsoft.Json"

Stacktrace: "   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateObject(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerMember, Object existingValue)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateValueInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerMember, Object existingValue)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.SetPropertyValue(JsonProperty property, JsonConverter propertyConverter, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerProperty, JsonReader reader, Object target)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.PopulateObject(Object newObject, JsonReader reader, JsonObjectContract contract, JsonProperty member, String id)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateObject(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerMember, Object existingValue)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateValueInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerMember, Object existingValue)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.PopulateList(IList list, JsonReader reader, JsonArrayContract contract, JsonProperty containerProperty, String id)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateList(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, Object existingValue, String id)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateValueInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerMember, Object existingValue)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.Deserialize(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, Boolean checkAdditionalContent)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.DeserializeInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize[T](JsonReader reader)
   at Azure4Educators.Business.Utilities.CosmosJsonNetSerializer.FromStream[T](Stream stream) in C:\\Users\\...\\source\\repos\\CosmosErrorDebugging\\CosmosErrorDebugging\\Class2.cs:line 40
   at Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.CosmosJsonSerializerWrapper.FromStream[T](Stream stream)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.CosmosSerializerCore.FromFeedStream[T](Stream stream)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.CosmosFeedResponseSerializer.FromFeedResponseStream[T](CosmosSerializerCore serializerCore, Stream streamWithServiceEnvelope)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.ReadFeedResponse`1.CreateResponse[TInput](ResponseMessage responseMessage, CosmosSerializerCore serializerCore)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.CosmosResponseFactoryCore.CreateQueryFeedResponseHelper[T](ResponseMessage cosmosResponseMessage)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.CosmosResponseFactoryCore.CreateQueryFeedUserTypeResponse[T](ResponseMessage responseMessage)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.FeedIteratorCore`1.<ReadNextAsync>d__8.MoveNext()"
```

Comment: `await container.CreateItemAsync(entity);` throws the exception *Cannot **deserialize** the current JSON object*?  That's a little surprising.  Can you share the full `ToString()` output of the exception including the exception type, message, traceback and inner exception(s) if any?

Comment: @dbc added exception details

Comment: That's the exception for the `GetItemLinqQueryable` query, right?  Can you also share the exception for the create statement please?

Comment: I was able to reproduce your exception outside of CosmosDB using a Json.NET fiddle here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/abeey8.  And I was able to resolve it by simply commenting out `MetadataPropertyHandling = MetadataPropertyHandling.Ignore`, see https://dotnetfiddle.net/ZpjWgn.  While that resolves the problem in the fiddle, does it work for you in production?

Comment: Incidentally, since your `"$id": "1"` isn't the first property in the JSON, setting `MetadataPropertyHandling.ReadAhead` might allow `PreserveReferencesHandling.All` to work, see https://dotnetfiddle.net/l8OHYi.

Answer (score 0):

this error mean you return one object and deserialize to list
if you return one object as json write it :

```
Entity _entity=Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Entity>(json_file);
```

if you return many object:

```
List<Entity> _entites=Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Entity>>(json_file);
```

Comment: if you want to remove $id from your json file please write your code that convert to json